# Perforce: run script as particular user and workspace

Tags: perforce

I have a powershell script that does various things, including running p4 commands such as syncing, creating a changelist and checking files into it, create a label etc. My script works fine when I run it on my development environment as my user.

Now I would like to run the script on another machine, against a specific workspace, and a specific Perforce user. Is there some set of commands I can add to the beginning of my script so that I can set the perforce user and use a specific workspace for the remainder of the script? If yes, I'd like to know 2 ways of doing this, one with the password in plain text (for testing and verifying), and one without it (for production use).

**Releated**: I think part of my problem is that I don't fully understand how the session user is determined. On the other machine, if I try to run any p4 command, I get the message: "*Perforce password (P4PASSWD) is invalid or unset.*" I got that message even if I try:

```
p4 login abc
```

"abc" can be anything and I get the same message. I must be wrong in thinking that the "login" command can be used to login as a particular user. I was expecting it to prompt me for abc's password, rather than telling me I need to set a password before I can login as someone else.

But if I type in this:

```
p4 login
```

I am prompted to enter in a password. But for what user would that be? My Windows account user? What if I don't have a perforce user with the same name as my windows account user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the doc page you need:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/envars.html

In general, this should do the trick (with the current version of the command line client that supports "p4 set" on all platforms):

```
p4 set P4USER=username
p4 set P4CLIENT=clientname
p4 login
```

The "p4 login USERNAME" syntax is used when you've already logged in as a super user to get a login ticket for a different user (with no password prompt).  Like all other commands, "p4 login" uses your P4USER to determine who you're running the command as.

Answer (score 1):

To Auto login via powershell, login -a means allow login from any ip...

```
$USER = "My.User"
$PASS = "P455w0rd"
Out-File -FilePath C:\p4pass.txt -InputObject $PASS -Encoding ASCII -Width 50
cmd /c "p4 -u $USER login -a < `"C:\p4pass.txt`" " 2>&1
```

To specify the user, workspace and server:port append the below before the perforce command... e.g:

```
p4 -u ${USER} -c ${WORKSPACE} -p ${perforce:1666} login -a

p4 -u ${USER} -c ${WORKSPACE} -p ${perforce:1666} sync -f -q //...#head
```

To specify a ticket, get the ticket from the command:

```
p4 tickets
```

and specify it with an upper case -P, e.g:

```
p4 -u username -P 5E8ED75FB5086BE82D9BCD5561D32AEE sync...
```